# Using ISBNdb.com API in Java

Tags: java, api, oop

Does anyone know how to use ISBNdb.com's API to get meta data for a book in Java? I would like to user to look up a book by its ISBN number and my program will autofill the title, author, publisher, and volume. I just need ISBNdb.com to give me the Strings for those attributes.

Any ideas?

Answer (score -1):

There is a maven dependency that gives easy access to the isbndb api.

Add this to your maven project

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>nl.ivonet</groupId>
    <artifactId>isbndb</artifactId>
    <version>0.3</version>
</dependency>
```

This dependency is available though maven central.

Note though that you need an isbndb account and an api key to do the requests. There is a limit to your daily usage. So if you want auto completion you might go though your quota fast.

Please have a look [here](http://ivo2u.nl/d3) for the open source project
or [here](http://ivo2u.nl/d1) for an article about how to access ISBNdb with a java api.